# Langchain for document chat with references

Tags: python, huggingface-transformers, langchain

I would like to use Langchain for a chat that answers based on documents we make available to a model with Langhchain. However, I would also like to give answers within the chat that make references/citations to the respective document, from which they got the information from.

Ideally, I also would like to self-host a model that is used by Langchain, i.e., I do not want to rely on a proprietary service.

Is such a thing possible? If so, how?

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking to add inline citations in the reply, it is possible.

You can use citations agent from langchain [here](https://python.langchain.com/docs/use_cases/question_answering/how_to/qa_citations).

In llama index there is a similar feature too [here](https://gpt-index.readthedocs.io/en/latest/examples/query_engine/citation_query_engine.html).

Comment: The link for langchain point to the [cookbooks](https://python.langchain.com/cookbook). Can you update it with the latest one?